# DropDownListFor enums in EF5 selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Like in [DropDownListFor enums in EF5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460152/dropdownlistfor-enums-in-ef5) I would like to generate a dropdown list from a code first EF enum.  The solution provided works but it does not set the selected value.  How I can do this?  I have tried the code below but it does not work (where the last parameter in SelectList re-represents the selected value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeID, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Models.OrganisationType)),model.TypeID))
```

I have answered my question.  The above code correctly sets the selected value in the dropdown. For some reason MVC did not like my enum and property names when I used the word 'Title' for my property and 'Titles' for my enum as below:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(BL.Titles)),Model.Title),"")
```

Also I am using one View for both Create and Edit and therefore had to add code to stop MVC trying to set the selected value before the object has been created:

```
@if(Model == null) {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonsTitle, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(HLRA.eForms.BL.PersonsTitle))),"")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonsTitle, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(HLRA.eForms.BL.PersonsTitle)),Model.PersonsTitle),"")
        }
```

Does anyone know a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonsTitle, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(HLRA.eForms.BL.PersonsTitle)))))
```

should be enough.

I don't like your condition:

> @if(Model == null)

You should have your Model defined and the property "PersonsTitle" should be set with your default value.