# Create a dropdown list from model using enum and Entity Framework scaffolding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, enums

Is there a way for Entity Framework to automatically create a dropdown list in HTML given that the model has an enum property? Here's what I currently have inside my model, but when running my project there's just a text box instead of a dropdown!

```
public enum MajorList { Accounting, BusinessHonors, Finance, InternationalBusiness, Management, MIS, Marketing, SupplyChainManagement, STM }
[Display(Name = "Major")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your major.")]
[EnumDataType(typeof(MajorList))]
public MajorList Major { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your `@Html.EditorFor` for the following:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Major, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

### Update:

As @StephenMuecke confirmed in his comment `EnumDropDownListFor` is only available in MVC 5.1, so another solution could be getting the enum values using `Enum.GetValues` method. One option to pass that data to your View could be using the `ViewBag`:

```
var majorList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MajorList))
                    .Cast<MajorList>()
                    .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                         {
                             Value =e.ToString(),
                             Text = e.ToString()
                         });
ViewBag.MajorList=majorList;
```

Or adding it as a property in your ViewModel in case you were working that way.

Later in your View you could use a `DropDownList`as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Major, ViewBag.MajorList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

According to the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460152/dropdownlistfor-enums-in-ef5) the following also should work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Major, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(MajorList))))
```

Another solution could be create your own `EnumDropDownListFor` helper (check this [page](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/10/01/building-a-useful-html-helper.aspx) if you want to read more about this kind of solution):

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HTMLHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
            values.Select(value => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = value.ToString(),
                Value = value.ToString(),
                Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
            });

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(
            expression,
            items
            );
    }
}
```

This way you can do the same that I suggested at the beginning of my answer just you need to reference the namespace where you declare your static class with your extension:

```
@using yourNamespace 
//...

 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Major, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm receiving the error "'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Project.Models.Member> does not contain a definition for EnumDropDownListFor and no extension method EnumDropDownListFor could be found"

Comment: `EnumDropDownListFor()` is only available in MVC 5.1 or higher.